# when I zoom in all the elements go to left, i want the page to be on center when i zoom in

Tags: html, css

When I zoom in my page, all the elements go to left side, they are not collapsed but i want the web page to be on center when I zoom. I have made a container class and added a margin:auto to it bu it does not change anymore. Hope somebody answer it exactly.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: irsans;
    src:url('../fonts/irsans.woff2');
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:100%; /* requierd width */
  background:red;
}
   
header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
}
.topnav{
    position: absolute;
    left: 334px;
    top: 2px;
    width: 552px;
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.topnav_items a{
    margin: 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: irsans;
    color: #333;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.topnav_items li a:hover, .topnav_items li a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8B9498;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
   <header>
    <div class="topnav">
     <ul class="topnav_items">
      <li class="fa fa-envelope-o" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="#">ارتباط با برنامه</a></li>
      <li class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="#">پیش بینی مسابقات</a></li>
      <li class="fa fa-desktop" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="#">تبلیغات</a></li>
      <li class="fa fa-download" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="#">نرم افزار مسابقات پیامکی 90</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </header>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put your container(better call it wrapper) insidw the header.
2. Give the Container a fixed with using the with of ur topnav.
3. put margin to margin: 0 auto;
4. tkae out all atribute related to position: absolut from ur topnav.

(If ur not happ with the result u can also try to give container a relative with. For example with: 50% margin: 0 25%;)

```html
 <header>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="topnav">
            <ul class="topnav_items">
              <li class="fa fa-envelope-o" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="#">ارتباط با برنامه</a></li>
              <li class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="#">پیش بینی مسابقات</a></li>
              <li class="fa fa-desktop" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="#">تبلیغات</a></li>
              <li class="fa fa-download" style="font-size:11px;"><a href="#">نرم افزار مسابقات پیامکی 90</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: irsans;
  src:url('../fonts/irsans.woff2');
}
body{
margin:0;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 25%;
  max-width: 552px;
}
 
header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
}
.topnav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.topnav_items a{
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: irsans;
  color: #333;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.topnav_items li a:hover, .topnav_items li a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #8B9498;
}
```